# Why does a Flex program wait forever and not print anything?

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I'm doing a translation of acronyms.  That is, if it finds 'OMS' print 'Organización Mundial del trabajo', but once I compile and run the program it runs infinitely.

I'm using Windows as a development environment. I have seen examples but I can't see where the error is. Here is the code:

```
%option noyywrap    
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}

%%
OMS {fprintf(yyout,"Organización Mundial del trabajo");}

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE*yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE*yyout=fopen(argv[2],"w");
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
    fclose(yyout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `FILE*yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");` you are declaring and initializing a local unused variable, while global `yyin` remains unchanged.

Comment: @n.m.: Your diagnosis is basically correct — I suggest adding it as an answer so the question can be given closure. Strictly, the local variable `yyin` in `main()` _is_ used in the corresponding `fclose()` (for all that it is a vacuous usage), but you're absolutely correct that the lexical analyzer will be using the global variable `yyin` (which is hidden in `main()` by the local definition).  Alfito: If you use GCC, you could use `-Wshadow` to get a warning about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE*yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
FILE*yyout=fopen(argv[2],"w");
```

These lines declare and initialize two *local* variables named `yyin` and `yyout`. They are closed in the end of the function, but otherwise remain unused (that is, no one does any input/output with them). They are not available to the rest of the program. Meanwhile, global variables `yyin` and `yyout`, which are entirely separate from these local variables, remain untouched.

What you need to do is simply remove `FILE*` from both lines:

```
yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
yyout=fopen(argv[2],"w");
```

Now the names `yyin` and `yyout` refer to the global variables that are known to the rest of the program.